# Exc_bad_access error when trying to delete item/index

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

**Technologies:** XCode 6, Swift, iOS 8.1.3, Maverick 10.9.5

When I use the simulator, it works fine and never errors. When I download the app to my phone, it errors when I try and delete a few items in a row. I've also tried dumping all the data and doing a clean run, but still errors on my actual phone. A friend ran it on his iPad and he could delete things no problem without error.

```
func delete(index: Int) {
    searches.removeValueForKey(tags[index]) /** It errors here 
}
```

The error message is EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20).

Deleting an item will cause the app to crash, but once I bring the app back up/run it again, I can perform the delete action without error. If I try and delete another item, it crashes, but I can immediately bring the app back up and I can perform the delete action without error.

Does this issue have to do with the software versions I am using? Something else? Thanks for your help.

Here is when I call it:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,
    forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            model.delete(indexPath.row)
            // remove UITableView row
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(
                [indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
}
```

How I create my search data:

```
 private var searches: [String: String] = [:]

 if let pairs = userDefaults.dictionaryForKey(pairsKey) {
    self.searches = pairs as [String : String]
 }

 func tagAtIndex(index: Int) -> String {
    return tags[index]
 }

 func queryForTag(tag: String) -> String? {
    return searches[tag]
 }

 func queryForTagAtIndex(index: Int) -> String? {
    return searches[tags[index]]
 }
```

Comment: You need to show us more informations where you call the delete-method etc.

Comment: Try printing the value of `index` and the contents of `tags` when you enter the `delete` function.  See if one or the other is not what you expect.

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` must be on the `tags[index]`, you are trying to access a tags with an index that is out of range. But without more code, we can't help you

Comment: I think EXC_BAD_ACCESS is whenever you have an object released by the ARC and your still accessing it. If it was out of range, it would have given the Out of range bounds exception.

Comment: @ChristianWoerz  and everyone: I added where I call the function above. The content is accurate when I dump the index and tags, at least as far as the actual search queries.

Comment: OK, how is `searches` defined and created?

Comment: @PhillipMills I added more code related to how I build my search data. Do you see anything there that might be an issue?